# Java @SuppressWarnings

Tags: java, annotations

In general, I prefer sort out all @SuppressWarnings in my codes but in some cases, tools I am using returns generic ones such as Collection.

Is there any way I can suppress this warning and way to specify reason for it like C# in Java?

Comment: So you want to only suppress warnings that deal with missing generics?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn them off in Eclipse compiler preferences

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid warnings in almost all cases doing some programming, even if you get a collection declared without generics, you can convert it. However, that always strikes me as wrong, where you take runtime memory and processor cycles just so that the compiler doesn't complain about something that works, but it doesn't know about it.

So when you decide that SuppressWarnings is the right thing to do, you can limit its scope by using it on a variable declaration instead of the whole method (for example) so that you can avoid over suppressing problems. And the annotation lets you specify one or more things that you are intending to suppress.

So you can do:

`@SuppressWarnings({"MissortedModifiers", "FinalStaticMethod", "FinalPrivateMethod", "CaughtExceptionImmediatelyRethrown", "UnusedCatchParameter", "EmptyCatchBlock"})`

(That is an actual example I found lying around - now the warnings there are IDE warnings more than compiler warnings, but you get the point).